# Incorrect Spacing with JPanels using BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

I have an annoying issue with my JPanels that use BorderLayout.

```
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0)); 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    panel.add(new Slot(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel.add(new MapGUI(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This is in the constructor of my Inventory JPanel. Slot() and MapGUI() are classes that extend JPanel. When the game runs, the screen looks like this:
[image]

Clearly the Panels are completely off, with both being off the screen. How can I fix this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with your layout per-say, but an issue with the information your panels are providing your layouts, that is, it seems that they don't override `getPreferredSize` and return appropriate information.  Of course I could be wrong, but since you've not provided a a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem all we can do is guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JavaDocs for the BorderLayout:

> The components are laid out according to their preferred sizes and the constraints of the container's size. The NORTH and SOUTH components may be stretched horizontally; the EAST and WEST components may be stretched vertically; the CENTER component may stretch both horizontally and vertically to fill any space left over.

Do you have the preferred sizes set?

You may want to try the [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) if you want to align the components vertically.

Comment: Thanks! I did not set the preferred sizes. I fixed the issue by using    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));  in each of the JPanel classes.